# Add hyperlink/label to checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, label, radiobuttonlist

How do I created a checkboxlist with a hyperlink/label next to (or under) the first list item?

E.g.

```
[] listitem1 *hyperlink*
[] listitem2
[] listitem3
```

OR

```
[] listitem1 
   *hyperlink*
[] listitem2
[] listitem3
```

I have tried using Repeatflow="Flow" but the hyperlink sits next to listitem3 instead.

Any ideas?

EDIT: my codes here:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" BackColor="#cee7ff" >
</asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Print Terms and Conditions</asp:LinkButton>
```

Note that checkboxlist is populated in code-behind (but I can also hardcode in aspx listitem if necessary)

Comment: Please add the code you have

Comment: Thanks nmat! I have updated!

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about just the position of the linkbutton, you can simply use css style like:

```
<div style="clear:both; float:left">
    <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Text 1>" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Text 2" />
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <asp:LinkButton Text="Click Me" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Or you can use jQuery like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        var theLink = $("#<%=lbLink.ClientID%>");

        // To place the link beside the first checkbox
        theLink.appendTo($("#<%=cbList.ClientID%> tr:first td:last"));

        // To place the link after the first checkbox
        // $("#<%=checkbox1.ClientID%> tr:first").after(theLink);
        // theLink.wrap("<tr/>").wrap("<td/>");
    });
</script>

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Text 1>" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Text 2" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbLink" Text="Click Me" runat="server" />
```